# Java -> Stream.filter() how to make it return a String

Tags: java, lambda, expression

So I have this assignment in which I need to use lambda expressions to make a filtered search. In short, I have a database of users and I need to print a message for each search that a user makes. What I did was:

```
 text=users.stream()
           .filter(c -> c.getName().equals(filter.getName()))
           .findFirst()
           .map( c -> {
               Final String message= c.getSearchOutput(filter.getTitle(); 
               return message;
           })
           .toString();
```

The problem is my text is something like

> "Optional:[*insert Final String message here*]"

and I need to be just

> *insert Final String message here*....

How can I improve this lambda expression? I need to do this because I have to parse text into a JSON object, and I apparently cant do it in the body of the lambda expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findFirst` returns an `Optional` so you can try using:

1. `Optional.orElse / orElseGet / orElseThrow` method:

```
text = users.stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getName().equals(filter.getName()))
    .findFirst().map( c -> {
        return c.getSearchOutput(filter.getTitle(); 
    }).orElse("");
```

2. `Optional.get` method:

```
text = users.stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getName().equals(filter.getName()))
    .findFirst().map( c -> {
        return c.getSearchOutput(filter.getTitle(); 
    }).get();
```

`Optional.get` will throw `NoSuchElementException` if your optional is empty so you may want to use the first option.

Comment: Thanks, this solved all my issues. I used the first option.